# Selenium RC and clicking on Panel links!

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to click on the panel links (links in the same page but different panel) in the page using Selenium RC. I'm able to do it by using:

browser.waitForCondition("selenium.isElementPresent(\"id=placeOrderLink\")", "30000")

but I want to make it generic and I tried to use:

String var="placeOrderLink";

browser.waitForCondition("\"selenium.isElementPresent(\\"id="+var+"\\")\"", "30000");

and it doesnt work! I get an error.
I'm using Java to code my test suite.

Answer (score 1):

Try this browser.waitForCondition("selenium.isElementPresent(\"id=" + var + "\")", "30000")

Answer (score 1):

BTW: you don't need "`id=`*controlID*" when specifying control ID's in locators - control ID locator is the default one, so "*controlID*" is enough.